# Get password value from the form angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a form

```
    <form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="changePassword(f)">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Current Password" name="currentPassword" [(ngModel)]="user.currentPassword"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="password" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" [(ngModel)]="user.newPassword" required validateEqual="confirmPassword" reverse="true" #newPassword="ngModel"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
            <ion-item  [hidden]="newPassword.valid || (newPassword.pristine && !f.submitted)" class="validation_error">
                <ion-label class="text-danger">
                    New Password is required
                </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="password" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confrim Password" [(ngModel)]="user.confirmPassword" required validateEqual="newPassword" reverse="false" #confirmPassword="ngModel"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item [hidden]="confirmPassword.valid || (confirmPassword.pristine && !f.submitted)" class="validation_error">
            <ion-label class="text-danger">
                Password mismatch
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <div class="space_lr">
            <button block ion-button>Done</button>  
        </div>
        <!-- /.space_lr -->
</form>
```

and I need to get the value of current password and new password.

The method I am trying is returning a blank with no error, and I am very much curious.

i have a function called

```
   account = {
     currentPassword: '',
     newPassword: '',
   };

 changePassword() {

  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });

  let callParams = {
    lmId: this.lmService.getSession('memberId'),
    currentPassword: this.account.currentPassword,
    newPassword: this.account.newPassword
  }
  console.log(this.account.newPassword) // returns blank
  .........
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe because you use `user.newPassword` instead of `account.newPassword` as `ngModel` in your template?

Comment: you have used the member variable name "user" in your template but "account" in the class

Comment: yes it worked.. thanks. Can someone make an answer so that I can tick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments:

You used `user.newPassword` instead of `account.newPassword` as `ngModel` in your template.

Comment: It worked.. Thank you. I am actually noob and learning angular 2